# FormsAuthenticate through WCF (How do I make the Session apply to browser?!)

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, rest

Users are authenticating to a REST WCF Service (my own). The credentials are sent through AJAX with Javascript and JSON format. The service reply with a OK and little info (redirect url) to the client, when authenticated.

Now, There are a new method provided for external authentication, and I have to create a compact code snippet that are easy to paste & run inside a asp.net code file method.

A typical wcf request could end up like this,
`http://testuri.org/WebService/AuthenticationService.svc/ExtLogin?cId=197&aId=someName&password=!!pwd`

My code snippet so far,

```
protected void bn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebHttpBinding webHttpBinding = new WebHttpBinding();
    EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(url);

    ContractDescription cd = 
        ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IAuthenticationService));

    ServiceEndpoint sep = new ServiceEndpoint(cd);
    sep.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
    sep.Address = endpointAddress;
    sep.Binding = webHttpBinding;

    var resp = new ChannelFactory<IAuthenticationService>(sepREST).CreateChannel();
    LoginResult result = resp.ExtLogin(cId, aId, hashPwd);

    Response.Redirect(result.RedirectUri);
    // I.e. http://testuri.org/Profile.aspx (Require authenticated to visit)
}
```

I recieve correct authenticated reply in the resp/result objects. So, the communication are fine. When redirecting to the actual website, I'm not authenticated. I can't locate the problem? If I take the URI above (with valid credentials) and paste into my Webbrowser URL, and then  manually type the uri, i'm authenticated.

I've spent a day searched the net for this, without success. 
There are a LOT of info but none seem to apply.

**What am I missing?**

I also tried another approach but the same problem persist.

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uriWithParameters);
 CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
 request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
 request.ContentType = "application/json";
 request.Accept = "application/json";
 request.Method = "GET";

 string result;
 using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
         using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
             result = reader.ReadToEnd();

 JavaScriptSerializer jsonDeserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 LoginResult contact = jsonDeserializer.Deserialize<LoginResult>(result);     
 Response.Redirect(result.RedirectUri);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this answer, but will offer it anyway as nobody else has posted:

I think it's because the request that has been authenticated is the request sent via code.
When you redirect it's a totally different request - so is still not authenticated.

All authentication techniques require some way of maintaining the authenticated state across 'stateless' requests = session cookies or some kind of authentication token.

Whatever token you get back from the call to the authentication service needs to be available to your website requests as well - dumping the token from the request into a cookie might be an option.

Can you see (in something like Fiddler) an auth token being sent as part of the request to 'RedirectUrl'?

Comment: Thanks for your try. I thinked about that. When server side code are authenticate, the client (web browser) dont know. If I make the uri request in the url, its a client request. But then, how do I make the client aware of the serverside authentication?

Comment: I *think* you can take the cookie off the HttpWebRequest request and save it to the web browser request - but I haven't tried it.

Comment: This are really killing me. The problem seems more connected to the fact that HttpWebRequest got thier own session (and act like they are on another page). Which means Session/Cookies when I Redirect, a new session from another domain are trying to reach the restricted area.